# How to delete parts of an image in Corona SDK?

Tags: drawing, coronasdk

I am trying to make a small game where I need to be able to delete the pixels of an image, where the user touches.

So, imagine you have an image that covers the whole screen.
The user can swipe inside the screen and the image's pixels are removed wherever the user touches, revealing anything that is below the original image.

The request is similar to the corona x-ray example (http://developer.coronalabs.com/sample-code/x-ray), but we need to be able to change the mask according to where the user has swiped. So, we cannot use a mask (as it the x-ray example), because the deleted pixels will not form a rectangle.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to delete pixels from an image in Corona, however you can do some creative masking, possibly, using the Crop Library created by Satheesh; http://web-c2.anscamobile.com/code/useful-crop-library